# Rhubarb wine colour lost after additives introduced

Tags: wine, color, yeast-nutrient, campden, pectic-enzyme

I'm making an Rhubarb wine. It's been 'dry sugared' for 3 days and the extracted syrup had a nice pink hue from the pink Rhubarb stems.

Yesterday evening I made the volume up to 5 litres and the pink hue remained. I mixed up 1tsp Pectic Enzyme, 1tsp Yeast Nutrient, and one crushed Campden tablet and stirred this in with a little water. As soon as I added these chemicals, the pink hue started to disappear, and within another 30 seconds of stirring, the diluted juice was just an off-white colour.

Any ideas what killed the colour? I'll be pitching the yeast this evening after a good aeration.

**Update 11th May:** Last night I pitched the yeast. This morning it's fermenting well and a pinkish-orange hue has returned. This makes me wonder if the colour-loss was due to the Yeast Nutrient and now that's being consumed, the effects are negated? Complete speculation!

Comment: This is just speculation, but if the pink color has anything to do with the small bit of pectin in rhubarb, then that pectic eznyme is going to take it right out.

Comment: @valverij yes! I wondered that? There's been a change actually, I've just edited my post.

Comment: I've also heard of campden tablets stripping some colors, but I'll let someone with more knowledge on the subject chime in on that one.

Comment: @valverij Ok I'm going to be putting a dandelion brew on later this evening, and expect that to be very yellow when I add the various additives. This time I'll add them one at a time and take note :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My initial guess was the Campden tablet's SO2 was the culprit and hunting around for similar stories I found this on a home brew forum:

http://www.homebrewtalk.com/showthread.php?t=267418

Observations in this thread would seem to fit with what you have experienced.

Comment: Thanks! Yep that makes sense and I can agree that it's reversible, the wine is looking pinky peach coloured now.

Answer (score 1):

I performed my first rack on some muscadine wine. I had 5 Camden tablets crushed and diluted in jug #2. Jug #1's content was deep pink. The content in the siphon line was pink. As soon as the wine touch the Camden/water solution in Jug [image]#2, it turned a hazy gold color.

Comment: So to answer the question, the campden has changed the color.  But did the color come back after a few days?

Comment: 6 days later and still the same gold color. It has started to clear but no bubbles since racking. Assuming maybe the Camden tablets stopped fermentation too.

Comment: 5 campden seems a lot (depends on the size of the tablets, but usually 2 is enough for 23L/5Gal ).  It might take a longer time to evacuate...

Comment: These were 550mg. Everything I've read says one per gallon. I guess I'll know next time.